# how to pole to RabbitMQ from Micro Service(SpringBoot) in a timely basis(Every 10 minutes) for 3 times

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

My Java Micro service (SpringBoot Application) detect the RabbitMQ connection lost because of RabbitMQ down. But how it should try to reconnect after certain time (for example 3 sec, 3 times). If still not able to connect  after 3 attempts then how to trigger a mail.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: My question is how to pole to RabbitMQ from Micro Service(SpringBoot) in a timely basis(Every 10 minutes) for 3 times.

Comment: please edit your question and add your last comment there. I will try to give you an answer

Comment: @jorj edited and in addition to that email event should trigger

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Spring Boot you can use Spring Retry functionality.

I don't have knowledge of RabbitMQ, so the code will be only for you to make an idea (will not compile).

Let say you have a method that try to connect to RabbitMQ, or try to send something to RabbitMQ:

```
@Retryable(value = {RabbitMQConnectinTimeoutException.class},
           maxAttempts = 3, 
           backoff = @Backoff (3000))
public boolean sendRabbitMQmessage(final String message) {
    RabbitMQConnection.sendMessage(message); // this method can throw RabbitMQConnectinTimeoutException
}
```

Using `@Retryable` annotation, Spring will retry your method 3 times when the method throw a RabbitMQConnectinTimeoutException, with a backoff of 3000 ms.

After the 3 attempts, if the RabbitMQConnectinTimeoutException still occurs, then the `sendEmail` method will be execute because of `@Recover`:

```
@Recover
public void sendEmail(RabbitMQConnectinTimeoutException e) {
    Email.send(YOUR_EMAIL_MESSAGE);
}
```

In the above example, I assume that you are calling `sendRabbitMQmessage` from another `@Service`. If you want to run this method every 10 minutes, you should annotate `sendRabbitMQmessage` also with the `@Scheduled`:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "600000", initialDelayString = "1000")
@Retryable(value = {RabbitMQConnectinTimeoutException.class}
           maxAttempts = 3, 
           backoff = @Backoff (3000))
public boolean sendRabbitMQmessage(final String message) { ... }
```